# Export to PDF with Nepali (Preeti, Kalimati) fonts in ArcGIS 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pdf, unicode, nepal

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2, created a map with Nepali (Preeti, Kalimati) fonts. Fonts not correctly displayed in exported PDF file. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @wetland](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261490/export-to-pdf-with-nepali-preeti-kalimati-fonts-in-arcgis-10-2-2/261515#comment414174_261490) you should review [Problem: Some symbols, markers, or fonts change or disappear when exported to EPS or PDF](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007619) which suggests a solution/workaround:

> As all ArcMap symbols and markers are stored in fonts, the best solution is to embed fonts used in the map into the output document.

However, it also warns that:

> Some fonts do not allow embedding or may not be valid fonts.

I think that you will only know whether embedding fonts will work for yours by trying it.

Comment: Tried embedding the fonts, but problem not yet solved.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution (for others who might have a similar issue) is to use one of the more standard, default fonts in ArcMap such as Arial.  What I've done to create maps in Dari is to have all my locations and features (what I want labelled) in an Excel document.  In Excel, I can ensure that all my feature names and labels are correct (or have a language specialist do that), then run an Excel to Table process.  After joining the new table to the features I want to label, labels displayed in a default (English) font will still be in the proper alphabet and retain structure and properties.  This may not be ideal in the sense that you cannot precisely control the presentation and design of the font, but it will export to PDF or any other format without issue.

Good luck!

Comment: Tried but not solved.

Comment: Sorry to hear - is the text present and appearing normal if you try exporting as a PNG file type?  A workaround might be to save that as a PDF, with the texts then embedded as an image.  The problem seems to be that the PDF export is encoding the texts from UTF8 to ANSI, without the option to retain the original formatting.